# using called functions to call timers in visual basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, function, timer

I'd like to know if there is a way to call a timer through a function. This function itself is called through an automated timer that is activated when the form loads.

```
Function callTimer(ByRef var1 As Integer, ByVal var2 As Integer)
    'statements()
    Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play() 'to ensure that it is called
    Call otherFunction(ByRef var3 As Integer) <-- how do you do this??
    Return var1
End Function
```

I want to know how this can be done. VB gives me an error when I try this or something like this.

Thanks all!

Comment: Would you mind sharing what the error is?

Comment: there are a few errors but they are errors that are quite obvious (using variables out of a Private Sub and stuff like that)

Comment: Paraphrasing you: I still don't understand your problem. Do you mind explaining it further? This is confusing, sorry :-(

Comment: What I want is to know how, if it is possible, to call a timer through a function and not have it automatically load when the form loads. I created an example function above and the `Call otherFunction(ByRef var3 As Integer` is what I'm looking to correct. The function callTimer itself is a function that is called by a timer (not shown in original question). It's basically like: onLoad timer calls callTimer (the function above) which calls another timer called otherFunction, which then runs a certain task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @competent_tech was saying is that you're defining a function within a function, which is illegal. You want to **call** the function, not define it. An example of this would be like so:

```
Shared _timer As Timer 'this is the timer control

Function callTimer(ByRef var1 As Integer, ByVal var2 As Integer)
    Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play() 'to ensure that it is called
    Dim testInt As Integer
    testInt = 4
    Call otherFunction(testInt) '<-- this calls otherFunction and passes testInt
    Return var1
End Function

Function otherFunction(ByRef var3 As Integer)
    StartTimer(var3) ' this will start the timer and set when the timer ticks in ms
                ' (e.g. 1000ms = 1 second)
End Function

'this starts the timer and adds a handler. The handler gets called every time 
'the timer ticks
Shared Sub StartTimer(ByVal tickTimeInMilliseconds As Integer)
    _timer = New Timer(tickTimeInMilliseconds)
    AddHandler _timer.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf Handler)
    _timer.Enabled = True
End Sub
'this is the handler that gets called every time the timer ticks
Shared Sub Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    ' . . . your custom code here to be called every time the timer tickets
End Sub
```

It seems like you might be a little confused with calling a function versus defining a function. Before you can use a function it must be defined, like my example code above.

Another thing to get a better handle on is the usage of **ByRef** versus **ByVal**. ByRef passes a reference to an address in memory. What this means is that any changes to the variable within a function will persist outside of the function. ByVal, however, will not persist outside of the function and the value before being passed to the function will be the same as after the function call. Here is an example of that:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim value As Integer = 1

    ' The integer value doesn't change here when passed ByVal.
    Example1(value)
    Console.WriteLine(value)

    ' The integer value DOES change when passed ByRef.
    Example2(value)
    Console.WriteLine(value)
End Sub

'any Integer variable passed through here will leave unchanged
Sub Example1(ByVal test As Integer)
    test = 10
End Sub

'any Integer variable passed through here will leave with a value of 10
Sub Example2(ByRef test As Integer)
    test = 10
End Sub
```

**Result:**

> test = 1
>
> test = 10

This ByRef/ByVal example can be seen [at this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/byval-byref). It's worth looking more into if you're still confused.

**EDIT**: This edit includes information regarding [invoking a timer in VB.NET](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer-vbnet).

Comment: Wait but I thought we could only use ByVal for functions because they return values? Thanks for the link. Does the `otherFunction()` have the capability of calling a timer?

Comment: @ChaseYuan The code has been modified to include an example of what a timer control use might look like. This example was modified from the referenced link above. I suggest you look more into how timers work. And also, I suggest reading more into ByVal versus ByRef if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining the method parameters, not setting them.

You need to pass a value, for example:

```
Call otherFunction(var2)
```

Comment: so what does `otherFunction` do, exactly?

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry I didn't use that as my function name so I forgot. So I don't need all the "byref" stuff? just the var2?

Comment: @ChaseYuan i think what he's saying is that you're defining a new method within a method, rather than **calling** a method. Check this link out regarding [VB.Net method usage](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=972) , maybe it will help.

Comment: @Sam I still don't understand this problem. Do you mind explaining this to me? this is confusing, sorry.